# Airflow | Scheduling URLs in batches over multiple days

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I need some suggestions related  to setting up scrapers with Airflow.

Issue is lets say i have a website to scrape that has  some 3k links. I want to divide this over 3 batches of 1k each and all these have to run on different days .

What can be the best approach in this case? If we can do some conditional parameter basis scheduling. Example I have excel as my data source so next to every url i can mention like Batch no ... now basis batch number if we can schedule differently?

Hope this makes some sense. Please suggest

Comment: The question is unclear can you add more details, Is it like first time the job runs then it has to process the first batch and so on, Why not have 3 different dags with 3 different schedules ?